# Business hours and labels in fullcalendar scheduler

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm trying to use scheduler in order to show classes time from one entire day. The problem is that class time is 50 minutes, and between some classes has interval.

I did that using business hours, but it has a strange behavior in labels. Labels do not respect business time, the only thing I could do is show labels from 50 to 50 minutes too, but it is not enough because of intervals.

See below how it shows:

[image: fullcalendar scheduler]

And now, how I would like it is:

[image: desired fullcalendar scheduler]

And here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');
    var YESTERDAY = todayDate.clone().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var TODAY = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var TOMORROW = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        resourceAreaWidth: 230,
        editable: true,
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        scrollTime: '07:25',
        slotLabelInterval: '00:50:00',
        slotDuration: '00:50:00',
        slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
        defaultView: 'timelineDay',
        resourceLabelText: 'Turma / Sub-turma',
        businessHours: [
            { id: 'a1', start: '07:25:00', end: '08:15:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a2', start: '08:15:00', end: '09:05:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a3', start: '09:20:00', end: '10:10:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a4', start: '10:10:00', end: '11:00:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a5', start: '11:10:00', end: '12:00:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a6', start: '12:00:00', end: '12:50:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a7', start: '13:15:00', end: '14:05:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a8', start: '14:05:00', end: '14:55:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a9', start: '15:10:00', end: '16:00:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a10', start: '16:00:00', end: '16:50:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a11', start: '17:00:00', end: '17:50:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a12', start: '17:50:00', end: '18:40:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a13', start: '19:00:00', end: '19:50:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a14', start: '19:50:00', end: '20:40:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a15', start: '20:55:00', end: '21:45:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] },
            { id: 'a16', start: '21:45:00', end: '22:35:00', dow: [0,1,2,3,4,5] }
        ],
        minTime: '07:25:00',
        maxTime: '22:35:00',
        resources: [
            { id: 'd', title: '1º Semestre', children: [
                { id: 'd1', title: 'Turma A', children: [
                    { id: 'd11', title: 'Sub-turma A' },
                    { id: 'd12', title: 'Sub-turma B' },
                ] },
                { id: 'd2', title: 'Turma B' }
            ] },
        ],
        events: [
            { id: 'e1', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T07:25:00', end: TODAY + 'T08:15:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e2', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T08:15:00', end: TODAY + 'T09:05:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e3', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T09:20:00', end: TODAY + 'T10:10:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e4', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T10:10:00', end: TODAY + 'T11:00:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e5', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T11:10:00', end: TODAY + 'T12:00:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e6', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T12:00:00', end: TODAY + 'T12:50:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e7', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T13:15:00', end: TODAY + 'T14:05:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e8', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T14:05:00', end: TODAY + 'T14:55:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e9', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T15:10:00', end: TODAY + 'T16:00:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e10', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T16:00:00', end: TODAY + 'T16:50:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e11', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T17:00:00', end: TODAY + 'T17:50:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e12', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T17:50:00', end: TODAY + 'T18:40:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e13', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T19:00:00', end: TODAY + 'T19:50:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e14', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T19:50:00', end: TODAY + 'T20:40:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e15', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T20:55:00', end: TODAY + 'T21:45:00', title: 'event ' },
            { id: 'e16', resourceId: 'd2', start: TODAY + 'T21:45:00', end: TODAY + 'T22:35:00', title: 'event ' },
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Please help-me!!

Best regards

Comment: Unfortunately AFAIK there is no way to make the calendar do this. The slot times have to be at equal intervals, and there's no functionality to add a break between slots in the way you're showing. Perhaps you should request it as a feature - details here: https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Requesting-Features/

Comment: Hi @ADyson, thanks for tip, but I have already done that, and until now no answers for my request. [See the topic](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/369)

Comment: In that case I think your only option is to attempt to modify the source code yourself and add such a feature.

Comment: I tried to do that, but I couldn't =(
If somebody can do that and need to pay money, we can pay for this

Comment: I'm not that person (simply don't have time), but there are websites where you can find consultants for hire who might have expertise. I guess maybe the fullCalendar guy doesn't have time right now either, or you might have had a swifter response :-(.

Comment: Well, I'm still trying to do that here, if somebody can help me I will thank you.